# Problems with accessing .proto files in Java

Tags: java, signals, protocol-buffers

Recently I've been trying to implement the Signal Protocol (by Open Whisper Systems) into my messaging app written in Java so that it can use end-to-end encryption. I've downloaded all the required files from the GitHub repository website (I will mention the link below) and added them into my Java project. I haven't yet utilised any of the Signal Protocol's functions, because it gives me an error in the library which I added.

When I tried to see what the error was, it showed me that an import cannot be resolved. The same error with the same import occured in several files. The thing is, I could not find any .java file in the entire libary which was called as the one in the import statement.

After searching for a while, I found 3 .proto files containing lines which as far as I realised, try to add them into a Java package by giving them the names of the files which were mentioned in the import statements.

So, if possible, could anyone explain how I can use these .proto files, and how I could solve the import problem? It would be of great help to me.

Kind regards.

Here are some additional pieces of information:

The GitHub website from where I got the files: https://github.com/signalapp/libsignal-protocol-java/tree/master

Pictures of the problem:

[The import error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ed96X.png)

[The .proto files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFREJ.png)

[The name of the file which was mentioned in the import inside of the .proto file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/af7d2.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Protocol buffers come with a *protocol buffer compiler* that generates the Java interface to the protocol buffers.  You will need to use that on the proto files to generate Java files.